# c# httpwebrequest can't read/see cookies ( connect-sid)

Tags: c#, node.js, express, passport.js

I am currently using  EO browser and trying to set up cookies  after my login.  I have manually tried to set the cookies to the EO browser ( connect-sid cookie) and it worked.   But when I make a HttpWebRequest  I can not see  cookie information in response headers or anywhere in response.  I am using Express and passport js  in the login authentication.

```
        CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        string param = "username=test@yahoo.com&password=123456";
        string url = "http://localhost:8080/login";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = param.Length;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;


        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            byte[] paramAsBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(param);
            stream.Write(paramAsBytes, 0, paramAsBytes.Count());
        }


        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {

            MessageBox.Show(response.Headers.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(response.SupportsHeaders.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(response.GetResponseHeader("Response Headers"));


            foreach (var cookie in response.Headers)
            {
                var properties = cookie.GetType()
                                       .GetProperties()
                                       .Select(p => new
                                       {
                                           Name = p.Name,
                                           Value = p.GetValue(cookie)
                                       });


                foreach (var property in properties)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(property.Value.ToString());

                }
            }
```

[This is the  result I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQvFQ.jpg)

[I would like to see or get this value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWpqp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Ok,  as always right after I post my question  I have found the solution -  >  I was doing redirect after login.  so when I remove it  I could able to see the  value.

Though, any idea  how can I  get the value of  SetCookie?